# Hey! Where did all the Go questions come from? And why aren't there any gorrible puns in this title?

Tags: discussion, migration

I've just migrated 26 questions from [The Game of Go](http://go.stackexchange.com/). That site (still in private beta) will be shutting down soon. However, there were some excellent questions asked there, and since Go is also on-topic here, it seemed a shame to lose them.

One thing you might notice are the board diagrams... There's [a proper renderer](http://meta.go.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-do-we-go-about-getting-the-markup-plugins-we-need/18#18) for these on the way, but until then they'll continue to be displayed as text.

Comment: Looking forward to board diagrams!

Comment: Some of the answers contain links to other questions.  Those links should be updated to point at the questions here, rather than on the Go site.

Comment: Good point, @bwarner - I've updated several of them, will check again later.

Comment: Why not "migrate" ALL (or nearly all) of them. (OK, if it's 26 questions out of 28 or 29, that's "nearly all.") Or are you doing it, say, 13 at a time?

Comment: @Tom There was indeed a discussion about this. Since there were close to 100 questions on GoSE, general consensus was to move only the most interesting. This also avoids flooding this site :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Shog for your work. The questions seemed to have been moved fine, and the board excellent renderer is working too!

I'll have a look at the question in the next few days and try to make sure they fit properly on BGSE (caption, tags, ...)

Comment: If there's anything else we can do to help with the integration, don't hesitate to ping me (here or via email). BTW: You should've gotten an email from someone on the Community team on a related topic; don't know if you've had a chance to look it over yet, but please do when you get time.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, I will :)